# Determine a getline() starting point in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, text, line

This is part of my code

```
string line;
ifstream file ("Names.txt");

int i;
for (i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
    if ('A' <= line[i] && line[i] <= 'Z') break;
}

string start = line.substr(i);
getline(file, start, '.');
cout << start;
```

I need to start reading a line from first capital letter until the first period in a text file. At the moment it successfully reads from the beginning of the file until the first period. So I have a problem with determining the starting point i (first capital letter).

I appreciate your help!!

Comment: `line` isn't initialized to anything, so `i` is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string line;                           // line is empty
ifstream file ("Names.txt");           // line is still empty

int i;                                 // still empty
for (i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {  // still empty, line.length() == 0
```

Does that help?  You need to read from the file, into line (using getline), and then parse the line.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream file ("file.txt");
    char temp;
    while(file>>temp)
    {
        if(isupper(temp)) break;//First capital letter
    }
    file.seekg(-1,file.cur);//rewind one char so you can read it in the string
    getline(file,line,'.');//read until the first .
    cout << line << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rathere than `file.cur` I prefer to use `std::ios_base::cur`

Comment: Mm thank you for your answer, I went the other way with just determining a starting point with integer and a capital letter but I'll test the possibilities of the functions which you've introduced here :)